# Where login session cookie is stored in Symfony?

Tags: php, cookies, authentication, symfony

The question is quiet simple but I ask me this question when after log on my website, I watched cookies information in my Web browser and I only saw `PHPSESSID` cookie...

So where Symfony stored login cookie and where can I see it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication tokens are (typically) stored in the session. The session ID is communicated through the PHPSESSID cookie and any authentication token is read from the session data on the server.

Storing additional authentication data on the client side (browser) is not required and not a good idea either, as you will be exposing this data to the user and it is easily manipulated.

Comment: But where I delete PHPSESSID cookie I am still connected

Comment: With regular form-based authentication? That is quite frankly impossible if you deleted the cookie and resent the request.